# Spark 1.5.1 not working with hive jdbc 1.2.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to execute hive query using spark 1.5.1 in standalone mode and hive 1.2.0 jdbc version.

Here is my piece of code:

```
private static final String HIVE_DRIVER = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
private static final String HIVE_CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/idw";
private static final SparkConf sparkconf = new SparkConf().set("spark.master", "spark://impetus-i0248u:7077").set("spark.app.name", "sparkhivesqltest")
                .set("spark.cores.max", "1").set("spark.executor.memory", "512m");

private static final JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkconf);
private static final SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
public static void main(String[] args) {                
    //Data source options
    Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
    options.put("driver", HIVE_DRIVER);
    options.put("url", HIVE_CONNECTION_URL);
    options.put("dbtable", "(select * from idw.emp) as employees_name");
    DataFrame jdbcDF =    sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(options).load();    
    }
```

I am getting below error at  `sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(options).load();`

**Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveResultSetMetaData.isSigned(HiveResultSetMetaData.java:143)**
    at

> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:135)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.(JDBCRelation.scala:91)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:60)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:125)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:114)

I am running spark 1.5.1 in standalone mode
Hadoop version is 2.6
Hive version is 1.2.0

Here is the dependency that I have added in java project in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Can anyone help me out in this?
If somebody has used spark 1.5.1 with hive jdbc, then can you please tell me the compatible version of hive for spark 1.5.1.

Thank you in advance..!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're unfortunately out of luck in terms of using the jdbc connector until it's fixed upstream; the "Method not supported" in this case is not just a version mismatch, but is explicitly not implemented in the [hive jdbc library branch-1.2](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/branch-1.2/jdbc/src/java/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveResultSetMetaData.java#L143) and even if you look at the [hive jdbc master branch](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/jdbc/src/java/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveResultSetMetaData.java#L143) or [branch-2.0](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/branch-2.0/jdbc/src/java/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveResultSetMetaData.java#L143) it's still not implemented:

```
public boolean isSigned(int column) throws SQLException {
  throw new SQLException("Method not supported");
}
```

Looking at the Spark callsite, `isSigned` is called during `resolveTable` in [Spark 1.5](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.5/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCRDD.scala#L135) as well as at [master](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCRDD.scala#L137).

That said, most likely the real reason this "issue" remains is that when interactive with Hive, you're expected to connect to the Hive metastore directly rather than needing to mess around with jdbc connectors; see the [Hive Tables in Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables) documentation for how to do this. Essentially, you want to think of Spark as an *equal*/replacement of Hive rather than being a consumer of Hive.

This way, pretty much all you do is add `hive-site.xml` to your Spark's `conf/` directory and make sure the `datanucleus` jars under `lib_managed/jars` are available to all Spark executors, and then Spark talks directly to the Hive metastore for schema info and fetches data directly from your HDFS in a way amenable to nicely parallelized RDDs.

Comment: Even in 2.3 now it's not supported https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/branch-2.3/jdbc/src/java/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveResultSetMetaData.java. The problem of having Spark to access Hive Metastore is fine-grained access control. How do we deal with that?