# Connet hive thift server via pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, hive, cloudera

I am trying to connect to a remote hive thrift server using cloudera hive driver: com.cloudera.hive.jdbc4.HS2Driver. I am able to connect to it but while running any sql query I am not getting data in result, but only column names. The code which I am using is:

```
df = spark.read \
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("driver", "com.cloudera.hive.jdbc4.HS2Driver") \
        .option("url", "jdbc:hive2://host:port") \
        .option("dbtable", db_name.table_name) \
        .option("user", usr) \
        .option("password", pwd) \
        .option("properties",{"UseNativeQuery": 1}) \
        .load()
    df.show()
```

I know from logs that it is transforming queries and adding a condition `where 1=0`. I think it is because of that. But i am not able to remove that.
How do i resolve this?

Comment: can you post full logs ?

Comment: `== SQL ==
SELECT * FROM (select 'table_name'.'col1' from db_name.table_name) foo WHERE 1=0
---------^^^
, Query: SELECT * FROM (select 'table_name'.'col1' from db_name.table_name) foo WHERE 1=0.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087779/sqlcontext-hivedriver-error-on-sqlexception-method-not-supported/48157865

I was going through this post, there it is mentioned that it converts column names to string literals.